# Calculating charge diffusion coefficient from Green Kubo relation

Tags: integration, correlation-functions, molecular-dynamics

I'm trying to calculate Haven coefficient in some crystal that I have assembled coordinates of N ions of oxygen in k time steps. I looked up equations in this article: [Pressure-Dependent Diffusion Coefficients and Haven Ratios in Cation-Conducting Glasses](https://doi.org/10.1021/jp070478q)

I'm using this equation (from the article) to calculate tracer diffusion coefficient:

$D^{*} = \frac{1}{3}\int_{0}^{\infty }<\overrightarrow{v(0)}\cdot \overrightarrow{v(t)}>dt$

Where <> is the velocity autocorrelation function and I know how to unwrap this equation using this site: [The Velocity Autocorrelation Function](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/%7Eucfbasc/Theory/vaf.html)

But when it comes to equation for charge diffusion coefficient I have no idea how to unwrap this equation to calculate it for example in Python:

$D^{\sigma} = \frac{1}{3N}\int_{0}^{\infty }\sum_{i,j}^{1...N}<\overrightarrow{v_i(0)}\cdot \overrightarrow{v_j(t)}>dt $

Can anyone tell me step by step how to calculate it? Thanks